# Enity Framework query result shaping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Based off the MVC Music Store sample, I'm trying to pre-fetch the albums along with the genre but only read specific data from the album and not the complete entity.

Here is the EF query:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
{
   // Retrieve Genre and its Associated Albums from database
   var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Include("Albums").Single(g => g.Name == genre);
   return View(genreModel);
}
```

Say I have a View Model with:

```
public class AlbumViewModel
{ 
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; } 
}
```

How would I alter the EF LINQ query to get both the genre info AND include the albums but only select the data listed in the View Model, not the enitire entity?

To do the View Model part, I would have done something like (VB):

```
From a In storeDB.Albums
Where a.Genre = genre
Select New AlbumViewModel With {
     .Title = a.Title,
     .Price = a.Price,
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be it:

```
(from g in storeDB.Genres
where g.Name == genre
select new {
    Genre = g,
    Albums = g.Albums.Select(a => new { Title = a.Title, Price = a.Price })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying include the albums with the genre as per the Music Store sample.